# Isometries are determined by 3 points

Tags: linear-algebra

How can one show that  an isometry(rigid motion) in $\mathbb R^2$ is uniquely determined by how three noncollinear points are mapped? I am trying to determine the rigid motions of $\mathbb R^2$. Thank you.

Comment: They're not! You need to know more than the image of three points to uniquely specify an isometry of 12-dimensional space.

Comment: @rschwieb I think she means the plane.

Comment: I forgot to write in $\mathbb R^2$. I am sorry.

Comment: @Anna I think some texts distinguish between "rigid motions" and "isometries" by excluding reflections from "rigid motions". It looks maybe like they are synonymous for you?

Comment: @rschwieb I thought they are the same. But I don't know!

Comment: @Anna I think the context clues us that they mean the same thing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a coordinate system is fixed, we can make use of the fact that every rigid motion is composed of a translation and a rotation about the origin. (Or, alternatively, a translation, proper rotation and a reflection.)

Suppose points $A\mapsto A', B\mapsto B'$ and $C\mapsto C'$. By hypothesis, both trios form congruent triangles.

We are free to pick our coordinate system with origin $A$. By using a rotation $R$, we can rotate the triangle so that $AB$ is parallel to $A'B'$. By looking at the orientations of $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$, we will know whether or not we have to make a reflection to make them line up.

Finally you follow with the translation $T$ which carries the origin $A$ onto $A'$.

So to summarize, one point is used to determine a translation, then two points are needed to determine rotation. One of those two helps you get two corresponding side to be parallel, and then the final point helps you determine orientation.

Comment: Thank you! But I want to determine the rigid motions of $\mathbb R^2$. my idea is to show that if an isometry $f$ is determined by 3 points then it must be either a rotation, translation or reflection.

Comment: @anna Typically it will be a combination of the three, and not just one of the types.

Comment: Yes, okay. But then can you use it to show that an isometry is determined by 3 points? If it is what I want to show afterwards.

Comment: @Anna What I wrote starts with three moving points and then describes how one can deduce the isometry. If that is not what you want to do, then I don't understand the question, as you are asking it.

Comment: I am trying to determine the elements in the group of rigid motions. You assume what they are. But it seems okay that what you do describes the isometry. But how do you show that the rotation, translation and reflection are all elements and there are no others?

Comment: @Anna Again, I have to say that *they are not the only elements*. It is right to say that they generate all isometries, though. The answer would take up too much space here, so how about I link you to a [PDF I found on the topic](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/LectureNotes2U.pdf)

Comment: But these notes use linearity of $\bar{f}$ to show that $\bar{f}$ is orthogonal and orthogonality to show that it is linear.

Comment: @Anna It uses the linearity of the inner product, yes, but as far as I can see, theorem 1 proves that an isometry fixing the origin is a linear transformation.